# Visual Studio editor's support for multiple lines c# comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

How do I comment C# code in Visual Studio like this?

```
/* Start of comment
 * Blah blah blah
 * And now the end of comment.
 */
```

The intention is that once I start the multiple line comment and press enter the editor will indent to the position of the '/', and then add " * " so after the last line I just add /.

I used to be able to do this, but I can't recall how :( Nothing more annoying!

Edit: 
The default behavior of the editor is that after I press enter it positions the mouse on the next line at the column just below the '/' and I have to manually add " * ". I'm sorry. I know that adding " * " every line is no big thing. But it bugs me!

Comment: This is the default behavior.

Comment: Btw, the `*` in the intermediate lines are not required. They are only decoration.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > under "Editor Help" section, check "Insert * at the start of new lines when..."